# TextView & Button Not Showing After Add DatePicker In Android

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

I am new in Android. I have an app which picks user date of birth Using This [DatePicker](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-date-picker-example.html) . When i add this feature XML elements like TextView & Button Not showing. How's that possible? May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective? Maybe this question too basic, but i did't find any suitable solution.Please Help me out

Here is my code :

```
public class UserDobActivity extends Activity {

DatePicker datePickerBirthday;
TextView textViewUserDate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_dob);



    ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    ab.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33CCFF"));     
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

 // create the date picker
    datePickerBirthday = new DatePicker(this);

    // hide the whole calendar view (works in api 11 or greater)
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= 11) {
        datePickerBirthday.setCalendarViewShown(false);
    }
 // create the TextView
    textViewUserDate = new TextView(this);
    textViewUserDate.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    // initialize the date to current date
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    String dateStr = sdfDateTime.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    String[] dateSplit = dateStr.split("-");
    int currentYear = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]);
    int currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]);
    int currentDay = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]);

    // to show date and day of week in the TextView
    setHumanReadableDate(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay);

    // initialize date picker listener
    // currentMonth - 1, because on the picker, 0 is January
    datePickerBirthday.init(currentYear, currentMonth - 1, currentDay, birthdayListener);

    // add to the container
    LinearLayout linearLayoutCalTvContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayoutCalTvContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayoutCalTvContainer.addView(datePickerBirthday);
    linearLayoutCalTvContainer.addView(textViewUserDate);

 // set the views for the activity
    setContentView(linearLayoutCalTvContainer);

    RelativeLayout layoutCalTvContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layoutCalTvContainer.addView(datePickerBirthday);
}

// the date picker listener
OnDateChangedListener birthdayListener = new OnDateChangedListener() {

    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker birthDayDatePicker,
            int newYear, int newMonth, int newDay) {

        try{

            // currentMonth + 1, to retrieve proper month
            setHumanReadableDate(newYear, newMonth + 1, newDay);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

// show the user a better date format
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") public void setHumanReadableDate(int newYear, int newMonth, int newDay){
    try {

        String clickedDate = newYear + "-" + newMonth + "-" + newDay;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = sdf.parse(clickedDate);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdfDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy 'is' EEEE", Locale.US);
        String dateStr = sdfDateTime.format(d);

        textViewUserDate.setText(dateStr);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_dob, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   moveTaskToBack(true); 
   UserDobActivity.this.finish();
}}
```

Here is XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/dobdetails"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />


 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >



</RelativeLayout>

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/ButtonUserDOB" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:text="@string/next"
     android:background="@drawable/customised_button_click"
     android:textSize="20sp"

      />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setContentView(linearLayoutCalTvContainer);` again after initially setting the layout `R.layout.activity_user_dob` as content view. This will override the previously set layout and everything contained in that layout will disappear. Why don't you create your complete layout solely in xml? Try something like this:

Put your DatePicker and TextView into your layout wherever you want them to be:

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textViewUserDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And after setting your layout with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_dob);` you can retrieve the instances of your `DatePicker` and `TextView` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_dob);

    // Get the instances of your DatePicker and TextView from the layout
    DatePicker datePickerBirthday = findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    TextView textViewUserDate = findViewById(R.id.textViewUserDate);

    // Continue with the rest of the setup
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= 11) {
        datePickerBirthday.setCalendarViewShown(false);
    }
    ...
}
```

But be sure to never again call `setContentView(...);` after you initially set the layout to be `R.layout.activity_user_dob`.

Comment: Done (y) . Your logic true